# Storing JSON objects without local storage?

Tags: javascript, json

I have created an shopping cart but it does not work on Microsoft Edge. So, can I store JSON object in array in website without localStorage because it does not work on Microsoft edge and IE?

Comment: No, you can't store __JSON objects__ in any form in any browser. Also, you should rather ask why your localStorage doesn't work in IE, since it has been supported since IE8, as well as in Edge since its first release.

Comment: You should think of prefixing browser vendors on some apis. That might be the issue with Ms Edge.

Comment: localStorage is definitely available on Edge and IE (even back to IE8). https://caniuse.com/#search=localStorage

Answer (score 2):

Solution is simple, stringify the objects and store the JSON string.

```
var cart = [{item:"socks"}];
localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart")));
```

Works in IE11 and Edge too.

Comment: Thanks but I have done it.So is there any way to pass variable from one page to another

Comment: Why, what is the problem with localStorage?